# How to delete site via CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is there a way to delete an app via Firebase CLI?

Our CI creates a temporary Firebase app for a feature branch (based on the CI build number), and then runs tests on it. At the end it needs to delete the app. I'm not entirely sure how this is done. `firebase disable:hosting` just disables hosting and does not delete the app. This is similar to how we would have used Heroku review apps or Heroku forked apps. A similar CI workflow can also be achieved on Google App engine via versions.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no public API to delete a Firebase backend.

The recommended practice is to use the same database for testing and (if needed) put each run in its own node under the root. So instead of creating/deleting a new database, you're just create/deleting a node in a single database.

Comment: My scenario is that of a static site, there is no Firebase DB involved. The CI deploys a static site based on the build number and run some tests on it. (think like a static faqs site).

Comment: Got it. That unfortunately just leaves the first line of my answer: there currently is no public API to delete a Firebase backend.

Comment: I saw that Firebase got major updates. Was there any solution for this question?

Answer (score 4):

The correct command is `firebase hosting:disable`, which make your site offline. You can not remove your project, instead you can overwrite it by creating a new one with `firebase init`.

More info here `https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `firebase  use <alias> --unalias`and then delete the project from the console https://console.firebase.google.com/

Check before the list of commands with the command `-h`